pine script issue historical result does not meet real time
I created a script that has an 80% success rate in deep backtesting on a 5-minute timeframe. This can be seen in the list of trades. However, after adding an alert, I've noticed that over the past 2 days, the alerts don't match the list of  trades. The alerts and list of  trades are not the same. How can I make them match? Do you have any ideas or whats the issue
i backtested and setup alerts but they did not match the real time result which gave wrong inputs

Do you use Japanese candles? Backtesting on Non-Standard Charts
